# Transfer markers from MyMaps to QGIS?

Tags: qgis, google-maps, kml, geocoding

I need to georeference a list of places. Unfortunately, my original file doesn’t contain addresses, it is made up of a list of famous locations, such as the St Mark Basilica, Miramare Castle, Scrovegni Chapel.
Google my maps recognizes these famous places, and so, even if my file doesn’t contain addresses, Google My maps can localize these places correctly on the map (in Trieste, Venice, Padua) and creates markers.

When I export a KML or KMZ file from My Maps and open it on QGIS, I only get a table containing the information.

I was wondering if you knew any tools in QGIS that do that or any other tool in the net? I saw that there are several people asking this question, but my case is rather different as I don’t have any street address field.

Comment: Geocode the locations from Wikipedia? like https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?lat=45.434444&lon=12.339722&zoom=8 [St Mark's Square]

Comment: I'm not very familiar with MyMaps, but it seems like there should be a way to add the lat/long before exporting to kml.

Comment: I have about 1300 records like that. How can I geogcode the locations automatically from Wikipedia?

Comment: Do you only get a *table* in QGIS, or do you get a layer showing the position of the points?

Comment: Only a table with no geographic information on it.

Comment: MyMaps locations/points that were generated from an address or place name search will show up on the map fine, but when exported to KML/KMZ it will not include the lat/lon coordinates.  This prevents abuse of MyMaps as a geocoding service. You'll want to find a real geocoding service or API to give you the lat/lon coordinates for that many points.

Comment: Do I have other options?